# what is current state of ios background tasks? is it possible?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, background-process

I want to make an app with location tracking while the app is in the background.

- This app should get the location and make a post request from it in every
  interval.
- But as I found in ios it throttles the background task and kills it
  after some time. Is there any Fix to make api calls while the app is
  in the background? Any workarounds etc.
- I'm using react-native to build this app by the way.
  other questions are old so I'm making a new one.

Comment: You don't need a generic "background task".   You need to support background location updates, probably with "always" location permission. This has been part of iOS for many years. There is no need to ask a new question. This has been asked and answered many many times

Comment: background task need to call a fetch call. And I'm trying to this in react native. Is it possible?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=ios+react+native+background+location seems to indicate that there are solutions

Comment: i need free solutions. This one is paid I think its hard to do that.

Comment: I simply linked to all of the results Google has for react native iOS background location.  Look beyond the first result